# Pandas: How to create master link records for all matched values in in multiple rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame as below with value pairs in 2 columns.

```
A       B
182269  182270  
654372  654374
619300  619301
654373  654374
```

I want to add another column that has row value representing all matched values in the pair of same row and all values in other rows matched by this pair of values.

Below is the expected result:

```
A       B       C
182269  182270  182269, 182270
654372  654374  654372, 654373, 654374
619300  619301  619300, 619301
654373  654374  654372, 654373, 654374
```

Can you please advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `networkx`, notice I did not convert the `set` to string , if you would like convert it do `join`

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'A', 'B')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
df['New']=[ y  for y in l  for x in df.A if x in y]
df
        A       B                       New
0  182269  182270          {182269, 182270}
1  654372  654374  {654372, 654373, 654374}
2  654373  654374  {654372, 654373, 654374}
3  619300  619301          {619300, 619301}
```

Comment: Thanks and it is a great approach! My only question is that it if my pairs in column A and B are not ordered, as shown in modified data frames in the question. The 'New' column would have connected components in wrong order. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @MAMS sort your AB columns by sort_values~

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S, do you know if there a way to collect list of other attributes for components in the same community and add back to the original data frame? For example, there could be a 'Name' column including names of items in column A. I want to add another column, which is similar to 'New' column but with a list of names. I tried using loops creating attribute lists and attach back to the df, but it was slow due to the big size of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.arange](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) where you can specify `start` , `stop` and `step`. It will generate an array with incremental values:

```
In [420]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[420]: 
        A       B  
0  182269  182270  
1  654372  654374  
2  654373  654374  
3  619300  619301  

In [418]: df['C'] = [np.arange(x.A, x.B+1, 1) for x in df.itertuples()] 
In [420]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[420]: 
        A       B                         C
0  182269  182270          [182269, 182270]
1  654372  654374  [654372, 654373, 654374]
2  654373  654374          [654373, 654374]
3  619300  619301          [619300, 619301]
```